# File.readline() and csv.reader(file) are not returning the final two columns in my csv file

Tags: python, file

my code is only returning the first 7 elements of each row, but not the final two elements. I have tried copy-pasting the data into another file but it hasn't worked. Nothing appears to be wrong with the file itself either.

```
with open("tr_cities.csv") as file:
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        print(row)
```

[Here is a photo of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJg0b.png)
Its interesting to note that it picks up the final two cells as a null cell and doesn't ignore them entirely. idk what to do

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C5s08JNdA8nZIPCbA5T9uQmutIgoZn5O/view?usp=sharing) is the file in question. Im running Ubuntu if it helps.

---

Here are a few lines as text of the file:

```
city,lat,lng,country,iso2,admin_name,type,population,population_proper
Istanbul,41.01,28.9603,Turkey,TR,Istanbul,admin,15154000,15029231
Ankara,39.93,32.85,Turkey,TR,Ankara,capital,5503985,5503985
Izmir,38.4127,27.1384,Turkey,TR,Izmir,admin,4320519,4320519
Bursa,40.1833,29.0667,Turkey,TR,Bursa,admin,2901396,2901396
Antalya,36.9081,30.6956,Turkey,TR,Antalya,admin,2426356,2426356
Konya,37.8714,32.4847,Turkey,TR,Konya,admin,2232374,2232374
Adana,37,35.325,Turkey,TR,Adana,admin,2220125,2220125
...
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include a small excerpt of the file in the question itself, as text we can copy/paste (not an image, not a video, not a piece of architecture which portrays the nature of the file through sublime constructional details). See also the guidance for providing a [mre] and note that many of us are not willing to click on Google Drive because they require us to log in in order to track us.

Comment: I have done the copy of the first lines for you...

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll keep that in mind for my next question

Answer (score 0):

This is because your file does not have data for the last two columns after the 196 record.

Your application is working properly.

See this:

[image]

And this is the output of the program:
[image]

Comment: I have added a photo of my output to the question. Mine doesn't even show the first few entries. They are just blank throughout :/

Comment: The output you put in the csv file also has no data and your program is correct. :)